# Localization in .rc files

Tags: c++

My application is localized for multiple languages (write in VS2005 in c++).

What would happen if the application is run in a language whose localized files does not exist? For instance I have not localized for Dutch. what would happen when its run on a Dutch pc?

Answer (score 0):

The load order is:

1. Primary language/sublanguage
2. Primary language
3. Language-neutral
4. English (skipped if primary language is English)
5. Any

(Taken from [MSDN Blog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194810.aspx)).

So in your case you might end up with any of the languages you put in the ressources. If you want to influence the language taken, you can set the threads locale before loading a ressource. That's the way I did in programs: if locale is German, then keep it, otherwise change it to English so that international users always see the English GUI.